# Joining data from two postgresql tables with a flag if data exists in second table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery, left-join

I have two tables. The `tools` table stores a list of all available tools a user can enable on our website.

[image]

The `user_tools` table keeps track of the tools each user has installed.
[image]

For example, if user with `user_id` `13` installs a tool with `tool_id` `'mailchimp'`, this will create a new row in the user_tools table containing `user_id` `13` and `tool_id` `'mailchimp'`.

We have a page on our website that displays all tools with the currently installed tools in one section and the not-yet-installed tools in a second section.

[image]

I would like to write a single SQL query to populate this page. The query must fetch all tools and include a boolean column called `installed` that is true if the user has installed this tool. How can I do this?

I think I need an `OUTER JOIN`, and perhaps an `EXISTS` clause, but cannot figure it out.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    CASE WHEN u.tool_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END installed 
FROM 
    tools t
    LEFT JOIN user_tools u ON t.tool_id = t.tool_id AND u.user_id = ?
```

This will return all tools, with the `installed` flag indicating whether each tool was already installed for the current user.

The question mark should be replaced with the id of the user that is currently browsing your website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` and `not exists`.  For the installed tools:

```
select t.*
from tools t
where exists (select 1
              from user_tools ut
              where ut.tool_id = t.tool_id and
                    ut.user_id = ?
             );
```

For the not-installed tools, replaced `exists` with `not exists`.

If you want this as a single result set, then you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       ( exists (select 1
                 from user_tools ut
                 where ut.tool_id = t.tool_id and
                       ut.user_id = ?
                )
       ) as user_has_tool
from tools t
where
```